# Declaring length of tuples in Python typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, static-typing

I'm wondering whether or not to submit to Tuple[float, ...] even though I know the length of the tuple.

I have a Point and a Rect class, and a property `aspoints` in the Rect class that is to return a tuple of the top-left and bottom-right corners, as two-tuples.

The iterator has type `Iterator[float]`, which I know will give me two floats. I want the return value of the property to be 
`Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]]`
because I know that the iterator will give me two floats for each point.

Should I submit, and just say that it will return a `Tuple[Tuple[float, ...], Tuple[float, ...]]`, leaving a comment in the documentation of the length of them, or is there a better solution?

Here's the code.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Iterator, Tuple

@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[float]:
        return iter((self.x, self.y))

@dataclass
class Rect:
    x: float
    y: float
    width: float
    height: float

    @property
    def tl(self) -> Point:
        return Point(self.x, self.y)

    @property
    def br(self) -> Point:
        return Point(self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height)

    @property
    def aspoints(self) -> Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]]:
        return tuple(self.tl), tuple(self.br)
```

The problem occurs in Rect.aspoints. From MyPy I get the following error:

> `error: Incompatible return value type (got "Tuple[Tuple[float, ...], Tuple[float, ...]]", expected "Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]]")`

Comment: Arguably, a function named `aspoints` should have a return type of `Tuple[Point, Point]`, instead of breaking the `Point` abstraction.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I am considering renaming aspoints to ascorners or something. The property is used to be passed further into an external library that only accepts a couple of two-tuples.

Comment: On a more pedantic note, properties should have nouns as names, not verbs. Consider `corners` as the new name.

Comment: True. I think I got caught up in the `astuples` function from Python dataclasses, as I was learning about this when I initially wrote the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend your `aspoints` function to cast the field types correctly:

```
def aspoints(self) -> Tuple[Tuple[float, float], Tuple[float, float]]:
    left = cast(Tuple[float, float], tuple(self.tl))
    right = cast(Tuple[float, float], tuple(self.br))
    return left, right
```

You can also fit everything in one line, but the readability suffers a lot from it. The [`cast`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/casts.html) function doesn't do anything during runtime, it just serves as an explicit way of telling mypy (or some other static type checker) that you know more about your types than can be expressed in the basic typing tools.

You should absolutely *not* change the return type of `__iter__` to be anything that is not an iterator, that would be very strange and confusing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that your knowledge of how many elements the iterator will return can't be encoded into a static type.

I'm not sure that overloading `__iter__` to iterate over a fixed number of elements is the best approach here, since you're basically using it as a trick to allow casting an object to a tuple.

Maybe it would make sense to add something like a "to_tuple()" method to the Point data class instead? You could declare the type there...

Edit: alternately, I guess you could destructure the output of the iterator, but you're still not saving a lot of code:

```
a, b = self.tl
c, d = self.br
return (a, b), (c, d)
```

Comment: But don't you agree that iterator over a point should yield the x and y values?

Comment: Sure - this is correct. It's just that `__iter__` can't declare how many elements it will return, so the expression `tuple(self.tl)` will always have the static type `Tuple[Float...]` rather than a fixed length.

Comment: Yes, which is my problem. I just feel bad about using custom methods for such things, when the built-in `__iter__` is so much nicer. Isn't it better to sacrifice typing explicitly rather than the user interface of the class?

Comment: Yeah, in lack of a better solution, I'll go with that edited answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: You don't really want to iterate over a `Point`; you just want a way to get a tuple of `float`s and you are only making your point iterable so that you can pass it to `tuple` directly. (Consider this: would you ever write code that looks like `for coord in Point(3, 5): ...`?)

Instead of defining `__iter__`, define a function that does what you really want: returns a pair of `float`s.

```
from typing import Tuple


PairOfFloats = Tuple[float,float]


@dataclass
class Point:
    x: float
    y: float

    def as_cartesian_pair(self) -> PairOfFloats:
        return (self.x, self.y)


@dataclass
class Rect:
    x: float
    y: float
    width: float
    height: float

    @property
    def tl(self) -> Point:
        return Point(self.x, self.y)

    @property
    def br(self) -> Point:
        return Point(self.x + self.width, self.y + self.height)

    @property
    def aspoints(self) -> Tuple[PairOfFloats, PairOfFloats]:
        return self.tl.as_cartesian_pair(), self.br.as_cartesian_pair()
```

In support of this approach, it also lets you write an *additional* method that also returns a pair of floats, but with different semantics:

```
def as_polar_pair(self) -> PairOfFloats:
    return cmath.polar(complex(self.x, self.y))
```

---

Regarding unpacking, defining `Point.__getitem__` rather than `Point.__iter__` is sufficient:

```
def __getitem__(self, i) -> float:
    if i == 0:
        return self.x
    elif i == 1:
        return self.y
    else:
        raise IndexError


>>> p = Point(3,5)
>>> p[0], p[1]
(3, 5)
>>> x, y = p
>>> x
3
>>> y
5
```

Comment: Although another good solution, the code is part of a larger library. So yes, I want the __iter__ method defined for situations like `x, y = some_point`. But thanks for the answer!

Comment: That raises a good point. There's no problem with having `__iter__` for that type of unpacking, just no need to use it *exclusively* instead of the `as_*_pair` methods I mention.

Answer (score 0):

Given the requirements, it seems that using `typing.NamedTuple` as the base class for `Point` is most appropriate. It would greatly simplify things since none of `dataclasses.dataclass` features are being used, nor does `Point` seem to need mutability in the example given.

```
from typing import Tuple, NamedTuple
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Point(NamedTuple):
    x: float
    y: float

@dataclass
class Rect:
    ...
    @property
    def aspoints(self) -> Tuple[Point, Point]:
        return (self.tl, self.br)
```

While we're at it, it seems that `Rect` might also more appropriately inherit from `typing.NamedTuple`  for the same reasons as already mentioned for `Point`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'll consider it, but remember that the classes have been simplified to illustrate the point of my question, without adding too much noise.